# How to convert decimal string value to hex byte array in C#?

Tags: c#, hex, arrays

I have an input string which is in decimal format:

```
var decString = "12345678"; // in hex this is 0xBC614E
```

and I want to convert this to a fixed length hex byte array:

```
byte hexBytes[] // = { 0x00, 0x00, 0xBC, 0x61, 0x4E }
```

I've come up with a few rather convoluted ways to do this but I suspect there is a neat two-liner! Any thoughts? Thanks

UPDATE:

OK I think I may have inadvertently added a level of complexity by having the example showing 5 bytes. Maximum is in fact 4 bytes (FF FF FF FF) = 4294967295. Int64 is fine.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have?

Comment: Do you know the maximum and minimum values you will have to deal with?

Comment: If you need only four bytes, Int32 is fine, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have no particular limit to the size of your integer, you could use [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this conversion:

```
var b = BigInteger.Parse("12345678");
var bb = b.ToByteArray();
foreach (var s in bb) {
    Console.Write("{0:x} ", s);
}
```

This prints

```
4e 61 bc 0
```

If the order of bytes matters, you may need to reverse the array of bytes.

> Maximum is in fact 4 bytes `(FF FF FF FF) = 4294967295`

You can use `uint` for that - like this:

```
uint data = uint.Parse("12345678");
byte[] bytes = new[] {
    (byte)((data>>24) & 0xFF)
,   (byte)((data>>16) & 0xFF)
,   (byte)((data>>8) & 0xFF)
,   (byte)((data>>0) & 0xFF)
};
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/8bHHth)

Comment: And `Array.Reverse` since it seems big-endian output is desired.

Comment: Where does this generate the fixed length array (`I want to convert this to a fixed length hex byte array`)?

Comment: @ChrFin This gives OP a variable-size array which he is free to extend. The important thing is that this approach would not truncate his data or throw an exception, no matter how many decimal digits is supplied.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight nice two-line answer - and thanks for demo!

Answer (score 4):

You can use Linq:

```
  String source = "12345678";

  // "BC614E"
  String result = String.Concat(BigInteger
    .Parse(source)
    .ToByteArray()
    .Reverse()
    .SkipWhile(item => item == 0)
    .Select(item => item.ToString("X2")));
```

In case you want `Byte[]` it'll be

```
   // [0xBC, 0x61, 0x4E]
   Byte[] result = BigInteger
     .Parse(source)
     .ToByteArray()
     .Reverse()
     .SkipWhile(item => item == 0)
     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert the string to bytes you can use [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter.GetBytes(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(Int32.Parse(decString)).Reverse().ToArray();
```

Use the appropriate type instead of `Int32` if the string is not allways an 32 bit integer.
Then you could check the lenght and add padding bytes if needed:

```
if (byteArray.Length < 5)
{
    var newArray = new byte[5];
    Array.Copy(byteArray, 0, newArray, 5 - byteArray.Length, byteArray.Length);
    byteArray = newArray;
}
```

Comment: Assuming the decimal string represents a value that fits in a 32-bit int.

Comment: Thanks - that's certainly an improvement on my attempt!  I'll give it a short while before accepting as best answer - as you never know ;-)

Comment: Can skip 3 bytes to give the same result as the OP: `var result = BitConverter.GetBytes(ulong.Parse(decString)).Reverse().Skip(3).ToArray();`